# Hue don't want create home directory for user - MapR

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hue, mapr

I use MapR and I want to create user from LDAP.

I can create my users but Hue don't want to create associat folder, I have this message : "Error getting user info for current user, *** (error 500)"

I try with local user but it's the same problem...

I have just mapr user and when I create a folder manualy it's OK but when I want to change group or owner I have this message : "Could not set owner/group mapr/default for path /user/test (error 500)"

I don't understand why I have these problems....

Please help me.

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

I have some news, I tested with MapR Sandbox and I have the same problem.

With Hue from Cloudera or Hortonworks it's working, when I create a user with Hue, a folder is automaticly create but with MaprR it doesn't working.

I always have this message : "Cannot make home directory for user toto." But if I create a UNIX user toto it's working...

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have this in log : "[11/Mar/2016 08:42:57 -0800] connectionpool DEBUG    "GET /webhdfs/v1/user/***?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=mapr&doas=*** HTTP/1.1" 500 None" but if i try curl with "GET /webhdfs/v1/user/***?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=mapr" (without doas) it's OK...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix the problem the right way, but my workaround was to do the following as root:

```
[root@maprdemo] ~]# adduser -G mapr --home /user/myuser myuser
```

Then add the user to Hue. I just noticed you mentioned doing something similar in your edit.  I'll leave this here in case the commands help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [it](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini#L385) by hue.ini